# Adjectival form of the verb despise?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, derivational-morphology

Saw the title of the movie where minions come out - "Despicable Me" - I was curious, as *despicable* has the suffix *-able*, what would be its verb form? Then, I thought, is it *de-spice*? Which made me read it *de-spice-able*.

However, after looking up the dictionary, I found that its verb form is *despise* and it is pronounced *de-spik-able*. Isn't it okay to use "despisable?" How did this happen? Are there more adjectives like this?

Comment: *practice* and *practical*?

Comment: This happened because Latin `C` turned into French `S` and that turned, eventually, into English /z/, all in certain places and not others, like sounds do. But the original Latin word was borrowed with the original `C` to stick -_able_ onto. There are millions of stories like this, btw; several for each word in the language.

Comment: It can be worse. Verbs ending in -ate often lose the ending when turned into adjectives: communicate/communicable, operate/operable, penetrate/penetrable. But not always : illustrate/illustratable, locate/locatable.

Comment: @JohnLawler But... but... that's the answer. How am I supposed to upvote your answer if you've not made it an answer!?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard ‘despisable’ used in educated British English. Although I do not accept web or word-processor spelling dictionaries as authorities, they do reflect a view of contemporary usage, and the web browser I am using as I write this (Safari, Mac, UK) underlines it as a misspelling. However, consulting two British printed dictionaries I find both words listed.

**Chambers (1993 edition)**

> **despicable** *adj* deserving to be despised…
>
> **despise** to look down upon with contempt, scorn, hate — *adj* **despisable**

**Oxford English Dictionary (1928)**

> **despicable**…1. to be looked down upon or despised, vile, base, contemptible
>
> **despisable**…1. to be despised or treated with contempt; contemptible, despicable. Now *rare*.

The first quoted use of despisable is 1340, whereas that of despicable is 1553.

**Conclusions**

1. The two words have identical meanings.
2. ‘despisable’ is the original word that was displaced by ‘despicable’ to the extent that it is now uncommon in educated British use.

**Recommendation**

Use ‘despicable’. It is perfectly correct and will be much more familiar to your readers as it is much more widely used than ‘despisable’.

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to the mark-down. If whoever marked it down still finds fault with it, I would be obliged if he could let me know why. Otherwise I would suggest that he consider reversing his decision.

Answer (score 0):

According to Dictionary.com, both "despicable" and "despisable" are acceptable, however "despicable" tends to mean *deserving to be despised*.

Comment: Also note the difference between "despicable" and "despised".